# Appium parallel testing - Junit

Tags: appium

I'm trying to run my tests on two devices. Each time I'm running the test its only run on one device. sometimes, for some reason, the log shows the test runs on device "x" but actually it's running on device "y".

My code right now is trying to store the current deviceID on Json file and leave it in a queue until it finishes with the first device.

This is my code:

```
package core.managers;

import api.android.Android;
import core.ADB;
import core.MyLogger;
import core.Timer;
import core.constants.Arg;
import core.constants.Resources;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class DriverManager {

private static String nodeJS = "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe";
private static String appiumJS = "C:/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js";
private static DriverService service;
private static String deviceID;
private static HashMap<String, URL> hosts;
private static String unlockPackage = "io.appium.unlock";

private static DesiredCapabilities getCaps(String deviceID){
    MyLogger.log.info("Creating driver caps for device: "+deviceID);
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", deviceID);
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("app", "C:/Users/maoz/Desktop/spotter89.apk");
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.mobileresearchlabs.spotter.ex.no");
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", ("com.mobileresearchlabs.spotter.SpotterActivity"));
    caps.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "com.mobileresearchlabs.spotter.SplashActivity");
    return caps;
}

private static URL host(String deviceID) throws MalformedURLException {
    if(hosts == null){
        hosts = new HashMap<String, URL>();
        hosts.put("ffc64100", new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"));
        hosts.put("4d00b9e74ed431df", new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4724/wd/hub"));


    }return hosts.get(deviceID);
}

private static ArrayList<String> getAvailableDevices(){
    MyLogger.log.info("Checking for available devices");
    ArrayList<String> avaiableDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList connectedDevices = ADB.getConnectedDevices();
    for(Object connectedDevice: connectedDevices){
        String device = connectedDevice.toString();
        ArrayList apps = new ADB(device).getInstalledPackages();
        if(!apps.contains(unlockPackage)){
            if(useDevice(deviceID)) avaiableDevices.add(device);
            else MyLogger.log.info("Device: "+deviceID+" is being used by another JVM");
        }
        else MyLogger.log.info("Device: "+device+" has "+unlockPackage+" installed, assuming it is under testing");
    }
    if(avaiableDevices.size() == 0) throw new RuntimeException("Not a single device is available for testing at this time");
    return avaiableDevices;
}

private static DriverService createService() throws MalformedURLException {
    service = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File(nodeJS))
            .withAppiumJS(new File(appiumJS))
            .withIPAddress(host(deviceID).toString().split(":")[1].replace("//", ""))
            .usingPort(Integer.parseInt(host(deviceID).toString().split(":")[2].replace("/wd/hub","")))
            .withArgument(Arg.TIMEOUT, "120")
            .withArgument(Arg.LOG_LEVEL, "warn")
            .build();
    return service;
}

public static void createDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
    ArrayList<String> devices = getAvailableDevices();
    for(String device : devices){
        try{
            deviceID = device;
            if(useDevice(deviceID)){
                queueUp();
                gracePeriod();
                MyLogger.log.info("Trying to create new Driver for device: "+device);
                createService().start();
                Android.driver = new AndroidDriver(host(device), getCaps(device));
                Android.adb = new ADB(device);
                leaveQueue();
                break;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Ignore and try next device
        }
    }
}

public static void killDriver(){
    if(Android.driver != null){
        MyLogger.log.info("Killing Android Driver");
        Android.driver.quit();
        Android.adb.uninstallApp(unlockPackage);
        service.stop();
    }else MyLogger.log.info("Android Driver is not initialized, nothing to kill");
}

private static void queueUp() {
    try {
        MyLogger.log.info("Queueing Up: "+deviceID);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("queued_at", Timer.getTimeStamp());
        JSONObject jsonQueue = Resources.getQueue();
        jsonQueue.put(deviceID, json);
        MyLogger.log.info("JSON Queue: "+jsonQueue);
        ServerManager.write(new File(Resources.QUEUE), jsonQueue.toString());
    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static boolean useDevice(String deviceID) {
    try {
        JSONObject  json = Resources.getQueue();
        if(json.containsKey(deviceID)){
            JSONObject deviceJson = (JSONObject) json.get(deviceID);
            long time = (long) deviceJson.get("queued_at");
            int diff = Timer.getDifference(time, Timer.getTimeStamp());
            if(diff >= 30) return true;
            else return false;
        } else return true;
    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static void gracePeriod(){
    int waitTime = 0;
    try {
        JSONObject  json = Resources.getQueue();
        Set keys = json.keySet();

        JSONObject ourDeviceJson = (JSONObject) json.get(deviceID);
        json.remove(deviceID);
        long weQueuedAt = (long) ourDeviceJson.get("queued_at");

        for(Object key : keys){
            JSONObject deviceJson = (JSONObject) json.get(key);
            long theyQueuedAt = (long) deviceJson.get("queued_at");
            //If we did not queue first we need to wait for the other device to initialize driver so there is no collision
            if(weQueuedAt > theyQueuedAt) {
                //But only if device queued first and recently, otherwise we can assume device was already initialized or no longer being used
                int diff = Timer.getDifference(theyQueuedAt, Timer.getTimeStamp());
                if(diff < 50){
                    MyLogger.log.info("Device: "+key+" queued first, I will need to give it extra time to initialize");
                    waitTime += 15;
                }
            }
        }
        try {Thread.sleep(waitTime);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static void leaveQueue(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonQueue = Resources.getQueue();
        jsonQueue.remove(deviceID);
        ServerManager.write(new File(Resources.QUEUE), jsonQueue.toString());
    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I run 2 appium servers with Junit?

Answer (score 1):

In your code I don't see how you expect JUnit to run in parallel: no @RunWith, no threads, etc.

You may look at this [sample](https://github.com/saucelabs/testobject-appium-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testobject/appium/junit/TestObjectAppiumSuite.java) to understand how it can be done with `org.junit.runners.Suite` or you can try already working solution like 
[AppiumTestDistribution](https://github.com/saikrishna321/AppiumTestDistribution) (its using TestNG, but solve exact same issue)